# Downloading Daum dataset

Tags: data-request, research

In [This paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5370157) and if you search more in some other researches, the Daum data-set has been used. As I searched it seems to be about www.daum.net.

Does anyone know how I can download this?

Comment: Why don't you ask Messrs. Kwon and Hong? They scraped the Daum web site for 5 years.